# jQuery selector :link not working with $.is() or $.filter()...?

Tags: jquery-selectors

It seems like the selector `":link"` is not supported by jQuery's `filter()` or `is()` function.  For instance, if I evaluate `$(":link")` on a page it returns multiple links.  If I evaluate `$(":link").filter(":link")` or `$(":link").is(":link")`, an error is thrown.  The error message is "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: link".

Is this by design?  Do `filter()` and `is()` not support the same CSS selectors is jQuery does generally?  Is there documentation as to the difference?

Comment: Can you tell where the documentation mentions a `:link` selector? Because I can't find it… (at least not here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I can't find it either.  It is supported for $("a:link") but not .filter().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patrick commented that jQuery defaults in some cases to the browser's built in [querySelector or querySelectorAll](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml) where it exists. So, `:link` appears to work on some browsers, but I wouldn't suggest using it as it seems to produce wonderfully bizarre results.

```
<a href="www.foo.com">Hello</a>

alert($("a").is("a")); // do it this way

// changes the anchor's CSS, but does not return the length
alert($(":link").css('background','yellow').length);
```

Demo: ​http://jsfiddle.net/xWPw7/4

Comment: Your third test doesn't actually fail (in Safari and Firefox anyway). The second test crashes so the third alert never happens. If you remove the second test so the third can run, Safari shows a length of 1, while FF shows 3. And CSS is properly applied to the link with `.css()`. Very odd. http://jsfiddle.net/xWPw7/3/

Comment: ...I know what it is. jQuery defaults in some cases to the browswer's built in `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` when it exists. Apparently `:link` is supported. http://jsfiddle.net/xWPw7/4/

Comment: @Patrick - you should probably post that as an answer, and I should delete this post.

Comment: Thanks everyone for chipping in.